# Expo router stack screen not working based on order

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo, expo-router

Expo stack screen not working , Not getting  load login page on first load  based on order by  insted (tabs) screen loading first. When iam trying to load my login screen first by changing screen order i'm not able to change it . I cleared catch and i did every possible things please helpme. Here is my _layout.tsx

```
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { SplashScreen, Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import { RootSiblingParent } from 'react-native-root-siblings';
import SignInPage from './screens/Login';
export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router';

// export const unstable_settings = {
//   // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
//   initialRouteName: '(tabs)',
// };

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* Keep the splash screen open until the assets have loaded. In the future, we should just support async font loading with a native version of font-display. */}
      {!loaded && <SplashScreen />}
      {loaded &&  <RootSiblingParent>
        <RootLayoutNav />
          </RootSiblingParent>}
    </>
  );
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
        <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login"  options={{ title: 'Log in' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="screens/Mylistings" options={{ title: 'Log in' }} />

        <Stack.Screen name="screens/Signup" options={{ title: 'Sign Up' }} />
       
        <Stack.Screen name="modal" options={{ presentation: 'modal' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Login.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import PasswordInput from '../../components/user/PasswordInput';
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Link, useRouter,Stack } from 'expo-router';
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast';
import { FirebaseError } from 'firebase/app';


const SignInPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const auth = getAuth();
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

      // Handle successful sign-in
      console.log('User signed in successfully');
      // router.push('../../one');

      // Perform any other necessary actions after successful sign-in
    } catch (error) {
      // Function to format Firebase error codes to user-friendly messages
      const formatErrorMessage = (error :any) => {
        switch (error.code) {
          case 'auth/invalid-email':
            return 'Invalid email address. Please enter a valid email.';
          case 'auth/user-disabled':
            return 'Your account has been disabled. Please contact support.';
          case 'auth/user-not-found':
          case 'auth/wrong-password':
            return 'Invalid email or password. Please check your credentials.';
          // Add more error codes and corresponding messages as needed
          default:
            return 'An error occurred. Please try again later.';
        }
      };

      // Handle sign-in error
      const firebaseError = error as FirebaseError;
      const errorMessage = formatErrorMessage(firebaseError);
      let toast = Toast.show(`Sign-in error: ${errorMessage}`, {
        duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
      });

      // If you want to use console.error for debugging
      // console.error('Sign-in error:', error);
      // Add any necessary error handling logic or display error message to the user
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
    <Stack.Screen options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={setEmail}
          keyboardType="email-address"
        />
        <PasswordInput
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={setPassword}
        />
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={handleSignIn}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>
            New User? <Link href={'./Signup'}>Sign Up</Link>
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Link href='./forgotPassword'>Forgot Password</Link>
     

      </View>
    </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
  },
  box: {
    width: '90%',
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 12,
    padding: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#4287f5',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default SignInPage;
```

Comment: I had the same issue ... seems `expo-router` is a bit different on how we expect it from `react-navigation`.  
So what I've done is read their docs and use it like they say:  
- `app/_layout` should include only the `<Stack />`  
- add the Splash screen as `index (.tsx/.jsx)`  
- `tabs/_layout` will use the `<Tabs>`  
It seems there is a order/sort logic in their `expo-router` which doesn't make any sense :)